# How to retain the values of Hidden Field at Page Refresh (F5)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

How can we retain the values of Hidden Field in Page Refresh (F5). I am setting the values on hiddenfield on a method. based on this value i am showing and hiding a Div. But i want to maintain the visibility of Div on page also at refresh.

For doing this i am using using Hidden Fields but the values are not retain in hiddenfield as page is refreshed.

```
if (some condition)
{
    divCtrlSave.Visible = true;
    hdnDivShowAlert.Value = "true";
}
else
{
    divCtrlSave.Visible = false;
    hdnDivShowAlert.Value = "false";
}
```

and now i have following check at page load:

```
if (hdnDivShowAlert.IsNotNull() && hdnDivShowAlert.Value=="true")
{
    divCtrlSave.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    divCtrlSave.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Did you goggled it...???

Comment: yes i have googled it before posting to stackoverflow...

Comment: I am not sure but you can use html5 local storage

Comment: Yes for sure i can use Html Local Db but my project is not in Html5

Comment: @RazoR there is a jquery plugin for this, http://www.jstorage.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you could store it into `HTML5` `localStorage` or in Session or `cookie`. You don't have any other option against devil `F5` refresh...

To store it in session you could use it like below.

```
Session["Value"]= Yourvalue;
```

To store in `localStorage` use below snippet.

```
var key = $("#key").attr('value');
var value = $("#value").attr('value');
localStorage.setItem(prefix + key, value);
```

Explained in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HMEVd/127/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want something specific to the client use a cookie or session value.

If you are looking something specific to the server use a static class, application or cache value.

Comment: i cannot use session, viewstate and Cookies are my last option do you have any other ideas...

Answer (score 0):

U can use JS web storage at client side, it will look something like that:

```
<script>
    if (some condition)
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem('divCtrlSave',true);
        sessionStorage.setItem('hdnDivShowAlert',true);
    }
    else
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem('divCtrlSave',false);
        sessionStorage.setItem('hdnDivShowAlert',false);
    }
</script>
```

and now at page load:

```
<script>
    var hdnDivShowAlert_storage=sessionStorage.getItem('hdnDivShowAlert');
    if (hdnDivShowAlert_storage && hdnDivShowAlert_storage=="true")
    {
        divCtrlSave.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        divCtrlSave.Visible = false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about a page refresh, I assume that you mean during a postback. The hidden field retains its value during a postback, so in the Page_Load method in the code behind do the check, like:

```
if (IsPostBack == true)
{
    if (hdnDivShowAlert.IsNotNull() && hdnDivShowAlert.Value=="true")
    {
        divCtrlSave.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        divCtrlSave.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not talking about the Postback... yes i know that the values are retain during postback... but in my case i am hitting F5(refresh) and not doing any postback...